# Emacs HTML5 flymake?

Tags: html, emacs, tidy, flymake

I am using nxhtml-mode to edit html files. Recently, I start to use HTML5 markups such as `<article>` and `<section>`. Flymake throws errors for those tags. Now, I am using tidy for html validation. The setting is like below:

```
(defun flymake-html-init ()
  (let* ((temp-file (flymake-init-create-temp-buffer-copy
                     'flymake-create-temp-inplace))
         (local-file (file-relative-name
                      temp-file
                      (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))))
    (list "tidy" (list local-file))))

(add-to-list 'flymake-allowed-file-name-masks
              '("\\.html$\\|\\.ctp" flymake-html-init))

(add-to-list 'flymake-err-line-patterns
             '("line \\([0-9]+\\) column \\([0-9]+\\) - \\(Warning\\|Error\\): \\(.*\\)"
               nil 1 2 4))
```

Is there any alternatives to tidy which supports html5? Thank you.

Comment: Do you use [tidy-html5](https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5)?